# How to make list in list, the result is not what i want. help me

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I want to make an array with random value, but the result is not what i want. please help me

```
ui1 = []
for i in range (3):
    ui = (random.rand(1, 2))
    ui = np.transpose(ui)
    ui1.append(ui)
    print(ui1)
```

and the result is like this

```
[array([[0.55828503],
       [0.05327795]])]
[array([[0.55828503],
       [0.05327795]]), array([[0.54830574],
       [0.43161689]])]
[array([[0.55828503],
       [0.05327795]]), array([[0.54830574],
       [0.43161689]]), array([[0.19176995],
       [0.16990981]])]
```

and i want the result is without "array" just like this [[xxxx,xxxx][xxxx,xxxx]]

Comment: Instead of `print(ui1)`, you should write your own function to print the array the way you want.

Comment: You are appending numpy arrays, to convert them to lists use `tolist`

Comment: `ui1` is a list of (2,1) shaped arrays.   `np.array(ui1)` will make a (3,2,1) shaped array.  The title says list in list, but the text says `array`.  Keep your terminology consistent, otherwise you will get mixed answers.  Words like `array` in the display aren't just for looks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ui` variable is of type `numpy.ndarray` so its printed that way, to get the expected output you need to:

1. convert `numpy-arrays`(ui) to `list` using `.tolist()` function of `numpy.ndarray`
2. use concat (+=), to add ui to ui1, instead of append to get a 2 dimensional list
3. eliminate `transpose` function

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

ui1 = []

for i in range (3):
    ui = (np.random.rand(1, 2))
    ui1 += ui.tolist()
    print(ui1)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0.14189306309813854, 0.16354616375767916]]
[[0.14189306309813854, 0.16354616375767916], [0.6569125084666053, 0.297727414477004]]
[[0.14189306309813854, 0.16354616375767916], [0.6569125084666053, 0.297727414477004], [0.0970596850634321, 0.0031047000241498646]]
```

Comment: please check the output ` [[xxxx,xxxx][xxxx,xxxx]]`. this is the format

Comment: @ExplooreX thank you I forgot to remove `transpose` I have updated the answer

Comment: Okk @Abhi_j, and thanks for new idea with basic step

Comment: @ExplooreX Thank-you. But I didn't get why transpose is used in the question and in your answer could you explain thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

As per requirement you need `1d kind list` but `np.transpose(np.random.rand(1, 2))` return as `2d numpy object`.  So,

**1.** First use [`np.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to get make it as `1d array`.
**2.** Then use [`np.ndarray.tolist`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) to convert it into `list`

```
import numpy as np

ui1 = []
for i in range (3):
    ui = np.transpose(np.random.rand(1, 2)).ravel()
    ui1.append(ui.tolist())
    print(ui1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[[0.44580988372803254, 0.648543978436401]]
[[0.44580988372803254, 0.648543978436401], [0.15899973846214366, 0.7142306516115241]]
[[0.44580988372803254, 0.648543978436401], [0.15899973846214366, 0.7142306516115241], [0.9684254127229089, 0.4865093871901571]]
```